# How can I create a Primary Key in Oracle when composite key and a "generated always as identity" option won't work?

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I'm working on an SSIS project that pulls data form Excel and loads to Oracle Database every month. I plan to pull data from Excel file and load to Oracle stage table. I will be using a merge statement because the data that gets loaded each month is a rolling 12 month list and the data can change, so need to be able to INSERT when records don't match or UPDATE when they do. My control flow looks like this: Truncate Stage Table (to clear out table from last package run)---> DATA FLOW from Excel to Stage Table---> Merge to Target Table in Oracle.

My problem is that the data in the source Excel file doesn't have any unique columns to select a primary key or a composite key, as it is a possibility (although very unlikely) that a new record could have the exact same information. I am unable to utilize the "generated always as identity" because my SSIS package needs to truncate at the beginning of each job to clear out the Stage Table. This would generate the same ID numbers in the new load and create problems in the Target Table.

Any suggestions as to how I can get around this problem?

Comment: Truncating the table does not reset the identity column. I have a table I have been been truncating, and the identity value just continues to climb. Try it out.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are choosing to use SSIS? I have an Oracle external table that runs a power shell script, the results of which is treated like any other data. No load table is needed. If I were you, I would look at an external table to extract the data from the spread sheet. The processing could then be scheduled as an Oracle job, eliminating the need to use SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and ETL. Instead of using a staging table, in SSIS use two sources: Excel file and existing production table. Sort both inputs and then perform a merge join on the unique identifier. From there, use a derived column transformation to add a new column called 'Action' which will mark a row as either an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE based on whether the join key is NULL. So:

1. NULL from file means DELETE (not in file, in database)
2. NULL from database means INSERT (in file, not in database)
3. Not NULL for both means UPDATE (in file, in database)

From there, use a conditional split to split rows to either a OLE DB Destination (INSERT),  or SQL Command (UPDATE or DELETE). You can now remove the stage environment and MERGE command from your process. This has the added benefit of removing the ETL load from the SQL Server, assuming SSIS is running on a separate server.

Note: The sort transformation has the option to remove duplicates.

Comment: My problem here is that I don't have a unique identifier and I'm having troubles coming up with one.

Comment: If you do not have a unique identifier then you will need to create one. In SQL Server, it is called an Identity value. Oracle 12c does this (https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1). But, keep in mind that if you do not have a means to uniquely identify the incoming records then it will be impossible to match them with existing records. So, you are left with truncating and re-loading a given file. How are you doing your MERGE?